# whitelisting params for model without controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I'm working on upgrading a rails `3.2.22.5` app to`4.2.10`, I am using `strong_params` to replace the `attr_accessible` feature but there are some models which do not have a controller for them and I know I can use the [protected_attributes](https://github.com/rails/protected_attributes) gem to support it but I was wondering if there are any other alternatives someone has tried to completely get rid of using `attr_accessible` because it is not supported on rails 5 and I don't want to go through all of this again when I go to `rails 5`.

Comment: show your model. You can use virtual attributes

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [strong_parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) gem to backport the Rails 4+ strong parameters.

The whole approach of whitelisting parameters in the model has been deemed deeply flawed since models are not aware of the request context.

You should be changing to controller based whitelisting ASAP. This also makes the whole concept of "whitelisting" a model without a controller void.

Comment: Yes, I'm using `strong_params` to whitelist in controllers with my upgrade, I want to figure out the best way to deal with this for models that don't have a controller and I don't want to use the `protected_attributes` gem now and go through about how to replace it in couple of months

Comment: Controller whitelisting makes the whole concept of "whitelisting" a model without a controller void. The whole purpose is separating out which params can be assigned to the model - in the controller. No controller - no whitelist.